# want to send a email using smtplib but problem with recievers address

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, smtplib

i have created a tkinter form in which user is asked to enter his email and when the asked details are submitted i want to send OTP to the address entered by user,but i am running into error which is reciever address is not valid(i guess).below,i am giving the code that shall be essential
'''

```
emailstring = tk.StringVar(root)
email = tk.Label(root, text="E-mail").grid(row=2)
email_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=emailstring).grid(row=2, column=1)
receiver_mail =emailstring.get()
root.mainloop()
sender_mail = "godsownprogrammer@gmail.com"
message = "This is a test program\nYou are Trying to register your Email\nYour otp is :%s", otp_generator()
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
s.starttls()
s.login("godsownprogrammer", "xxxxx")
s.sendmail(sender_mail, receiver_mail, message)'''
```

i have trimmed non essential parts
now here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/91970/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/tk_new/main.py", line 63, in <module>
    s.sendmail(sender_mail, receiver_mail, message)
  File "D:\python 3.7\lib\smtplib.py", line 881, in sendmail
    raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'': (555, b'5.5.2 Syntax error. n24sm4653515pgl.27 - gsmtp')}
```

Comment: `receiver_mail` is empty string. Try moving `receiver_mail = emailstring.get()` to before `s.sendmail(...)`.

Comment: Move all the sending part to inside a function.

Comment: as@CoolCloud suggested,i tried to move all the sending part into the function but the same arises.now when i have moved it inside the mainloop,the tkinter application doesnt start as a result, no email address is given as input